# MySQL: How to get data id for 1 week starting on Monday

Tags: mysql

```
 -------------------------
| idproduct  |    date    |
|-------------------------|
| idp001     | 2017-05-01 |
| idp003     | 2017-05-05 |
| idp005     | 2017-05-07 |
| idp007     | 2017-05-08 |
| idp010     | 2017-05-09 |
 -------------------------
```

I have try this code :
`SELECT * FROM product where date between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 week) and now()`

it result :

```
 -------------------------
| idproduct  |    date    |
|-------------------------|
| idp003     | 2017-05-05 |
| idp005     | 2017-05-07 |
| idp007     | 2017-05-08 |
| idp010     | 2017-05-09 |
 -------------------------
```

but i want result like this and first day of week monday

```
 -------------------------
| idproduct  |    date    |
|-------------------------|
| idp001     | 2017-05-01 |
| idp003     | 2017-05-05 |
| idp005     | 2017-05-07 |
 -------------------------
```

Comment: Storing a string incrementing id is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `weekday()`:

```
where date >= curdate() - interval 7 + weekday(curdate()) day and
      date < curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) day
```

`weekday()` returns 0 on Monday and then increments for subsequent days.  This code uses `curdate()` because it explicitly has no time component.  And, it prefers `>=` and `<` over `between`. The time component can cause unexpected results using `between`, so I just never use it for date/times.